# selenium TimeoutException: in automating whatsap

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp, browser-automation

i am automating whatsap by using selenium and python script. I am trying to open chat by using xpath.it works well with recent chats, but when i try to open chat from contacts it raises TimeoutException.

here is my code:

```
import traceback
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =  'F:\driver\chromedriver.exe')
chrome_browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
time.sleep(15)
#print('scanning is completed')

wait = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser , 30)
user_name = "sakshi clg"
#user = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title="{}"]'.format(user_name))
#user.click()
#visibility_of_element_located  element_to_be_clickable
#wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH , "//span[@title=User_name]"))
try:
    user=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,"//span[@title='{}']".format(user_name))))
    user.click()
except TimeoutException:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

exception details:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/whatsap_prj/main.py", line 25, in 
user=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,"//span[@title='{}']".format(user_name))))
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\whatsap_prj\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

please someone help me.I am new to selenium.

Comment: Update your question with stacktrace

Comment: base on your script, you are waiting for an element with xpath //span[@title='sakshi clg'] , have you tried to look it up manually if it really exists?

Comment: yes this element exists.

Comment: The reason why you are encountering TimeoutException is because it's trying to look for that element but it cannot find it. Maybe you can share you dom or html so we can help you

Comment: can you please tell me how to share dom or where it is located?

Comment: In chrome, go to More tools > Developer tools . Under "Elements" tab, copy part of the html that contains the element you are looking for.

Comment: <span dir="auto" title="sakshi clg" class="_3ko75 _5h6Y_ _3Whw5"><span class="matched-text _3Whw5">sakshi</span> clg</span>

Comment: this is what i found in dom.Timeoutexception encounters whenever i try to find xpath of whatsapp contact with whom i haven't contacted recently.code works fine when i open chat of recent contact.